# Show UIPageViewController that doesn't take whole screen

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'd like to show a book on landscape iPhone that would use page curl from UIPageViewController, but I'd like book not to take the whole screen.

To clarify, let's say background is a wooden desk image and there is book on it that can be browsed using UIPageViewController and page curl but only book pages participate in page curl, background is completely static.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have a UIPageViewController using on half the screen for example. The secret is to add it into a parent view controller that is a [custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but what does that mean?

Comment: just set frame for your UIPageView controller then addSubview to the main controller. [self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];