# iOS (iPhone only): Horizontal page scroll, where the scrolling page doesn't take up the whole screen

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to achieve horizontal page scrolling effect (partial view, not of the entire screen scrolling), like in the [HGPageScrollView](https://github.com/100grams/HGPageScrollView) component.

[image: HGPageScrollView]

I am a fairly novice iOS programmer, and I am having difficulty finding the parts of the code which provide just the horizontal scrolling with the swipe gesture. So I am looking for any help, either some sample code, or pointers to the code in the HGPageScrollView, which provide just the horizontal scrolling functionality (i.e. not even the UIPageControl dots at the bottom, just the vanilla scroll).

I am only looking for an implementation which works in iPhone landscape orientation, if that makes it any easier.

Why I am not using HGPageScrollView:

1. It is not ARC compliant.
2. It does way more than I need it to, I am just looking for the scrolling.
3. Consequently, it is proving quite difficult for me to find where to remove all the features I do not need, like clicking on page to change the scrolling mode to full screen (HGPageScrollViewModePage)
4. I would like to use this as an incentive to learn more about the components available in cocoa-touch, and roll my own implementation.

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122925/show-uipageviewcontroller-that-doesnt-take-whole-screen) might be suggesting the solution, but I do not know how to implement it. I guess I don't fully understand it, as there aren't enough details for my novice skills to go on.

Comment: Simply use a UICollectionView, just google it and you will find a lot of tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UICollectionView and set the pagingEnabled property to YES.

If you want to do complex layouts of the items (like in your example above where items are split on both sides of the screen) you may want to provide your on UICollectionViewLayout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayout

Comment: Thank you. Ideally I would like to keep iOS 5 compatibility in my current project. How would  I go about implementing it in iOS 5? I found [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) for using UICollectionView in pre ios 6, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Yes, PSTCollectionView is the preferred way then. But do look at the penetration of iOS6/7 in whatever market you're targeting before deciding to support iOS5. In some markets iOS5 usage seems to be down to single-digits, so it may not be worth tying yourself to that version.